# Amortized analysis on Operations of stack

Tags: algorithm, stack, time-complexity, amortized-analysis

Let's Suppose we perform a sequence of operations (i.e., top, push, and pop) on an initially empty stack
so that the stack size does not exceed k. After every k operations, we make a copy of the entire
stack for backup purposes.
How can I use the accounting method to prove that each stack operation will have O(1) amortized
complexity regardless of whether the stack is copied or not?

Comment: Next time please provide something you have tried and not just a question.

Answer (score 1):

You have `k` simple operations and one copy operation that takes at most `k` time.

Together you make `p` elementary operations, and `p < k + k = 2*k`

So amortized complexity per operation is `p/k <= 2*k/k = 2 = O(1)`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How can I contact you with more questions?

Comment: You can make another questions for all SO users  :)

Comment: could you please check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461849/using-the-potential-and-the-accounting-methods-in-amortized-analysis

Comment: There is no need to ask for personal assistance. If question is interesting, somebody will answer it. But don't forget to show your own efforts.